# Woo-Commerce No Product Images just White

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

for my woocommerce site at http://tartangrand.com/home-v13-2/ if you scroll down to the the point where you can see some products, all of them are white the image refuses to show up unless I go under quickview.

never mind fixed thanks!

Comment: The ones not showing are base64 encoded. Did you try decoding to see what returns? The browser can't find them!

Comment: The images on your homepage have a src of `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=` which is a 1x1 pixel. Is there a setting that you need to update on a plugin or post to make them display the correct image? This looks like a placeholder display.

Comment: I know that, they are I believe woocommerce's placeholder display for products. but I can't get rid of it no matter what is edited.